# A row of dots at top in tables appear by themselves

Tags: php, debugging, browser, html-table

I use tables, but I just noticed that for some reason an extra row containing a few dots appear at the top.
Like this:
[image]

I checked in here for the same error, but it's only mentioned af few places where the problem seems to have something to do with Visual Studio extensions. But I only use php debug, and it still happened after I deactivated it. It also happens when I run my code on a browser.
It seems to have something to do with the amount of records I place in the table, at least the number of dots is the same as the number of records.
And as mentioned, it is also shown in the browsers debugger. I use FireFox but it also appears on Chrome and Edge.

[image]

Here is the code.

```
 echo "
  <div class='tabeldiv'>

  <table style='color: blue; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;'>
    <tr>
      <th style='width:4%; width: 60px;'>Id</th>
      <th style='width:20%;'>Navn</th>
      <th>Grupper</th>
      <th style='width:20%;'>Tekst</th>
      <th style='width:18%;'>Note</th>
      <th style='width:18%;'>Foto</th>
      <th style='width:6%;'>Pris kr</th>
      <th>Rette</th>
    </tr>";
    for ($i = 0; $i != count($Retter); $i++) 
    {
      $S 
      = "<tr>
        <td style='width:4%;'>" . $Retter[$i]->Id . "</td>
        <td style='width:15%;'>" . $Retter[$i]->Navn . "</td>
        <td>" . $Retter[$i]->Gruppe . "</td>
        <td>" . $Retter[$i]->Beskrivelse . "</td>
        <td style='font-size: 12px;'>" . $Retter[$i]->Note . "</td>
        <td style='text-align: center;'>" . $Retter[$i]->KortFoto();

      $Z = $Retter[$i]->Foto;   
      if ($Z != "") {
        $Z = $RestaurantensNr . "/" . $Z;
        $S = $S . "<img class='foto' src=$Z alt=$Z>";
      }

      $S = $S . "</td> . 
        <td  style='padding-right: 2px; text-align: right;'>" . $Retter[$i]->PrisTilStr() . "</td>
        <td>
        <form action='EditereRet.php' method='post'>
          <input type='hidden' name=".MadId." value=".$Retter[$i]->Id."> 
          <button class='tabelknapbredde' formaction='/KopierRet.php'>Kopier</button>
          <button class='tabelknapbredde' formaction='/SletRet.php'>Slette</button>
          <button class='tabelknapbredde'>Rette</button>
        </form>";
                    
        $S = $S . "
          <td>
          </tr>";
      echo $S;
    }
    echo "</table></div><br>";
```

I assume it has something to do with some built-in testing facility of some kind, and so probably something I can easily switch off, but what?

Poul

Comment: You have a dot in your text at `"</td> . ` as it's in the quotes it will be included in the output.

Comment: I'll be damned. I must have seen the dot a concatenation operator. Sorry about that.